# Apple Watch app won’t download on iPhone XR

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore, apple-watch, apple-watch.app

I recently got a new iPhone XR. When I restored it from a backup, I realized that the Watch had offloaded. I tried reinstalling, but it didn’t work. I deleted the app from my Home Screen.

Now whenever I go into the App Store to install it and tap on the cloud icon, it loads as if it’s about to start installing for half a second, then changes right back to the cloud icon. The app never installs, and I’m stuck because it leaves my Apple Watch useless as it can’t pair to my new iPhone.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Hey Mark! Can you try a different network?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) What is the version of iOS running on your iPhone XR?